# Why regex "\\[\\]" is redundant in Java?

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I want to match just the bracket `[]`, in my code:

```
// #peekToken() -> String
do { ... } while (context.peekToken().matches("\\[\\]"));
```

the intellij says:

[image: Intellij says about brackets]

and the auto-fixing makes it into:

```
"\\[]"
```

Why are they the same?

Comment: Because a `]`, when the pattern isn't currently inside a character set, doesn't need to be escaped to match a literal `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the character "close bracket" `]` is not a regular expression unless there was a bracket opened `[` before. Therefore it is redundant to escape it `\\]`, since Java is smart enough to know we are searching for the character itself in that case.

You can read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more informations on contexts where characters are percieved as regular-expressions.

Comment: `s/Java/regex/g`